# Services in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new with Angular and I am trying to bring some structure in my website I am building with Angular.

Now I have a Controller where I have some functions which I use on multiple pages. I have heard that I could better make a service out of these functions. How am I able to do this?

This is my Controller in current state:
How can I make a service from $scope.city function and $scope.specials function?

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope,$http){
  $scope.city = function(){
    $scope.items = [];

    $http.get('/getdata').then(function(d){
      $scope.items = d.data;
      $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
    },function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

  /* Function for specialization data */
  $scope.specials = function(){
    $scope.special = [];

    $http.get('/specialdata').then(function(d){
      $scope.special = d.data[0];
    },function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [Angular Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
 app.factory('getServiceData', function($http){
 return {
    getSpecials: function() {
      return $http.get("/specialdata")
     }
   };
});
```

and for use it in controller inject factory or service into controller as you see in bellow.

```
 app.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope,getServiceData){
 getServiceData.getSpecials().then(function(response){
        $scope.special =  response.data[0];
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), Here is an example

```
//Service.js
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp')
    .service('myService', service);

    service.$inject = ['$http']
    function service($http) {
        this.specialdata = function () {
            return $http.get('/specialdata')
        }
    }
})();

//Controller.js
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('DataCtrl', DataCtrl);

    DataCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'myService']
    function DataCtrl($scope, myService) {
        /* Function for specialization data */
        $scope.specials = function () {
            $scope.special = [];

            myService.specialdata().then(function (d) {
                $scope.special = d.data[0];
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        };
    }
})();
```